# How to get the Tkinter Label text?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Im making a list of addresses that the user will select from, and the address text will be  returned. I need to use `Tkinter.Label` because the `Tkinter.Listbox` will not allow for newlines.

The kicker is there is no `.get()`-like method in the Label class...

I know I can do something like:

```
v = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=v).pack()
v.set("New Text!")
 ...
print v.get()
```

However, I have a list of 5-20 address' keeping a seperate array of `StringVar()`'s will be difficult b/c I have no way of identifying the loc of the active label.  I would like to just access the activated widget contents.

Is `Tkinter.Label` the right widget to be using?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To get the value out of a label you can use the [`cget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method) method, which can be used to get the value of any of the configuration options.

For example:

```
l = tk.Label(text="hello, world")
...
print("the label is", l.cget("text"))
```

You can also treat the object as a dictionary, using the options as keys. Using the same example you can use `l["text"]`.

Comment: cget() did the trick!!!  Im kinda new to Tkinter, but this method seems quite useful!  I shall add it to my grimoire.  Thanks Again!

Answer (score 18):

```
label = Label(text = 'Hello, World!')
print(label['text']) # output is: Hello, World!
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, an explanation is needed to make it to an answer.