# Python - Tkinter check if this label empty or not empty

Tags: python, tkinter

**Hello guys I need to check if this label empty or not empty:**

**If not empty active some button.**

**I get the filename from another method.**

**this is the code :**

```
lb = Label(self, text="",  background='white')
lb.config(text=excel_name)
```

[image]

Comment: You should look into official documentation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Tkinter Label text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6113152/7414759)

Comment: I see all this, Nothing work this not entry text the is the display text

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple app that demonstrates a button being activated or disabled based on whether a label's text is the empty string or not:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.lb = tk.Label(self)
        self.lb.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="A button", command=lambda: print("Button pressed"))
        self.button["state"] = tk.DISABLED
        self.button.pack()

        self.bind("<Return>", self.enter_pressed)

    def enter_pressed(self, event):
        self.lb.config(text=self.entry.get())

        self.button["state"] = tk.NORMAL if self.lb["text"] else tk.DISABLED


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

The window contains a label, then a text entry box, then a button. If you type text into the text entry box then press the enter key (return key), the label text is set to the text in the text box, and the button is set to either enabled or disabled depending on if the label text is empty or not.

The key line here is:

```
self.button["state"] = tk.NORMAL if self.lb["text"] else tk.DISABLED
```

This sets the button state to either `tk.NORMAL` (enabled) or `tk.DISABLED` depending on whether the label text (`self.lb["text"]`) is the empty string or not.

Comment: Nothing work this not entry text the is the display text

Comment: @john I'm sorry, I don't understand your problem. You asked for how to get text from a label, and this code will do that for you. Maybe update your question with more detail?

Comment: Yes this code is give text from label but , I need to create function to know if this label is not empty click some button

Comment: Do you mean you want a function which, when you call it, simulates a button press if the label text is empty? e.g. if a have a label `lb` and a button `button`, if `lb` is empty, then do the command that is bound to `button`?

Comment: Yeh if lb empty don't deactivate button and if lb not empty active button

Comment: Edited. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes I do it in in one function by this code         if self.path:  # if file is selected
            self.buAccepte['state'] = 'active'  # enable button, I need to add  # enable button in another function