# Tkinter Widget class comparison

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a simple convertion GUI using Tkinter, however when I try to follow a logic where I'm comparing the text of 2 of my Labels to follow different paths it is not working. I'm very new exploring this so it maybe not even possible and I should use a different type or approach this on a different way.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or how should I approach my solution? Thank you :)

```
from tkinter import *

# Convert from Miles to Km or from KM to Miles depending on the label text
def convert():
    print("Conversion succeed!")
    value_to_convert = int(input.get())
    current_metric = my_label
    if current_metric == "Miles":
        new_value = value_to_convert * 1.60
        value_label.config(text=new_value)
    else:
        new_value = value_to_convert / 1.60
        value_label.config(text=new_value)

# Change the label text based on the current metric
def reverse_metrics():
    current_metric = my_label
    if current_metric == "Miles":
        my_label.config(text="Km")
        other_label.config(text="Miles")

window = Tk()
window.title("Distance Converter")
window.minsize(width=300, height=100)
window.config(padx=10, pady=20)

# Label
my_label = Label(text=" Miles", font=("Arial", 20))
my_label.grid(column=2, row=0)

# New_Label
new_label = Label(text="is equal to", font=("Arial", 20))
new_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

# New_Label
other_label = Label(text="Km", font=("Arial", 20))
other_label.grid(column=2, row=1)

# Value_Label
value_label = Label(text="0", font=("Arial", 20))
value_label.grid(column=1, row=1)

# Button
button = Button(text="Calculate", command=convert)
button.grid(column=1, row=2)

button = Button(text="Reverse Metrics", command=reverse_metrics)
button.grid(column=0, row=0)

# Entry
input = Entry(width=10)
print(input.get())
input.grid(column=1, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

I try to compare `my_label` text to `other_label` text so depending on that value my program will convert from Km to miles or from Miles to km. Comparison it's wrong not sure why.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112482/how-to-get-the-tkinter-label-text) help at all?

Comment: Use `my_label["text"]` to get the text of the label.